# My background image is being drawn too big for the canvas

Tags: java, android, image, layout, drawing

The background I'm trying to draw for my app seems to be getting scaled too large for some reason. I made sure the emulator is WVGA800, have it set up in the manifest and layout to be full screen and landscape (just like the image which is 800 x 480). I just don't see where it would scale the image.

Here's a picture of the problem. The image when put in the emulator, and then the actual image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRIFk.jpg]

Here's some relavant code:

```
/* mBackground instantiated in the class constructor */
mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.background );

private void doDraw( Canvas canvas )
{
        canvas.drawBitmap( mBackground, 0, 0, null );
}
```

Here's the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.project.game.GameView
        android:id="@+id/game"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what are the physical dimensions of the actual png file?

Comment: 800 x 480, same as the full screen canvas

Answer (score 1):

one possibility is to create a canvas with a viewport

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.cal_blank);
  canvas.setViewport(800, 480);
  canvas.drawBitmap(iconImg, 0, 0, new Paint(););
}
```

another way is to scale your image with this method http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

Comment: Tried the viewport, same result. My image shouldn't need scaling because the app is full screen at 800 x 480 (also landscape), and the image is the same resolution

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess - maybe it depends on what folder type is used to put the image in. Could you say where did you put the image? I mean, is it the `/res/drawable-hdpi/` or anything else? Have you tried `/res/drawable-nodpi/`?

Comment: /res/drawable currently. Do I need the qualifiers?

Comment: @Justen: Ok, then try to move it into the '/res/drawable-nodpi/' (create the 'drawable-nodpi' dir if not present). I vaguely recall the drawables put in '/res/drawable-nodpi/' will not be auto-scaled by OS.